# How to make COUNTIF only count subtotal for visible records when filter is applied

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like a formula to `COUNTIF` the `Brand 3` column and if filtered the `COUNTIF` changes to filtered criteria.

```
                    TOTAL COUNT 0        0          3   COUNTIF(H3:H5,"VoID")
Area    Region  Branch  Member  Brand 1  Brand 2    Brand 3 
East    NY        NY     1                           Void   
West    CA        LA     2                           Void   
North   IL      Chicago  3                           Void
```

With filter applied I get the same total count but need it to be 1 instead (count only the visible cells):

```
                    TOTAL COUNT 0        0          3   Answer needs to be 1
Area    Region  Branch  Member  Brand 1  Brand 2    Brand 3 
East    NY        NY    1                            Void
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking? Could you add a sample section of the sheet?

Comment: Please provide an example in a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET(H3,ROW(H3:H5)-ROW(H3),0)),(H3:H5="void")+0)
```

That will give you a count of visible cells in `H3:H5` (after filtering) that are "Void".